# Convert nested list into dataframe, with 0 if value is missing

Tags: python, list, dataframe

I want to convert:
`[['S1', 'S2', 'S6'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S3', 'S4', 'S5'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S5'], ['S1', 'S2', 'S4', 'S5']]` into a DataFrame with labels as `'S1','S2','S3','S4','S5', 'S6'` and 
If the value is not contained then that should be replaced by 0 otherwise 1.

```
 'S1','S2','S3','S4','S5','S6'
1 |  1     1   0    0     0    1
2 | 1     1   1   1     1     0 
3 | 1     1   0   0     1     0
4 | 1     1   0   1     1     0
```

This command is not good enough:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(res, columns = ['S1','S2','S3','S4','S5']) 

     S1  S2  S3    S4    S5
0    S1  S2  S6  None  None
1    S1  S2  S3    S4    S5
2    S1  S2  S5  None  None
3    S1  S2  S4    S5  None
4    S1  S2  S4    S5  None
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, convert from lists `['S1', 'S2', 'S6']` into dicts `{'S1': 1, 'S2': 1, 'S6': 1}`. We can construct a data frame from that, and Pandas will correctly put everything in the right place. Any values that are missing will be assigned NaN (and their columns will be set to a float dtype). To counter that, we'll fill the missing values with zeroes, then convert everything back to ints. So, assuming your data is in `data`:

```
pd.DataFrame([{k:1 for k in l} for l in data]).fillna(0).astype(int)
```

EDIT: If you don't like your columns to be in a seemingly random order, you can pass the `columns` keyword argument as you did in your attempt.